# How to prevent a request scoped bean method being called multiple times in a JSF application?

Tags: jsf, httpsession, thread-safety

Ok, with all the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616601/is-httpsession-thread-safe-are-set-get-attribute-thread-safe-operations) I'm still not able to handle my problem.
I have the following constellation:

In a JSF (1.1) webapp I have a request scoped bean `bean`of class `Bean`. When the user quickly clicks a `commandButton` multiple times to redirect him to the `insult.xhtml` page the `doSomethingThatTakesALittleLongerAndShouldOnlyBeDoneOnce`method may get invoked multiple times (on Tomcat 6). How can I prevent this?

```
...
public Bean() {
    HttpSession session = ((HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
             .getExternalContext().getSession(false));
    if(session != null && session.getAttribute("done") != null) {
        doSomethingThatTakesALittleLongerAndShouldOnlyBeDoneOnce();
        session.setAttribute("done", "done");
    }
}

public void doSomethingThatTakesALittleLongerAndShouldOnlyBeDoneOnce() {
    this.bossInsult = generateBossInsult();
}
```

insult.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<html>
    <body>
    #{bean.bossInsult}
    </body>
</html>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the bean session scoped and annotate the method with `@PostConstruct`. If you insist in keeping it request scoped, split that part out into a session scoped bean and make it a managed property of the request scoped bean using `@ManagedProperty`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{insultBean}")
    private InsultBean insultBean;
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class InsultBean {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.bossInsult = generateBossInsult();
    }
}
```

Then JSF will take care that it's created and called only once during the session.

---

**Update**: sorry, you're using JSF 1.x. If it's 1.2, then the following achieves the same:

```
public class Bean {
    private InsultBean insultBean;
}
```

and

```
public class InsultBean {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.bossInsult = generateBossInsult();
    }
}
```

and

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>insultBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.InsultBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.Bean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>insultBean</property-name>
        <value>#{insultBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Aww. Excuse me for not being precise enough with my example. I'm bound to JSF 1. I've experimented with putting bean in session scope but with the same result :(

Comment: Thank you. So I'm doomed with JSF 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Make the button disabled with javascript once it's clicked.

Comment: This would work, unfortunately the real situation is a little different from my example. The redirect occurs from a third party page that is out of my control.