# Synchronizing on a instance variable in a session scoped spring-bean to limit concurrent requests to a legacy service

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, httpsession

Due to a legacy system that doesn't handle multiple requests in parallell from the same user, I need to limit the amount of concurrent calls. The goal is to limit the number of concurrent requests to the service to 1 pr. user (session) - but ***not*** to have it block across all users. I could queue all ajaxrequests on the clientside, but that seems like a sledgehammer solution to a problem that only applies to certain calls. I'd like to solve this on the serverside if possible.

Alt. 1: possible problem might be that the autowired service is a proxy 
(due to requestscope) injected by spring and that the injected proxy 
reference might change across requests? Or does Spring reuse the same proxy - in which case it will work?

```
@Scope("session")
public class Model {
    @Autowired
    Service service;

    public List<Pojo> getPojos() {
        synchronized(service) {
            if(!hasTriedToRetrievePojos) {
                hasTriedToRetrievePojos = true;
                service.getPojos();
            }
        }
    }
}


@Scope("request")
// Actually a LegacyService, wrapping an old legacysystem
public class Service {
    ...
}
```

Alt. 2: if Spring only constructs one instance of this Model pr. session this should work as intended.

```
@Scope("session")
public class Model {
    private Object lock = new Object();

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    public List<Pojo> getPojos() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if(!hasTriedToRetrievePojos) {
                hasTriedToRetrievePojos = true;
                service.getPojos();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alt. 3: inject the HttpSession in Model and manually synchronize on a HttpSession ***property*** (according to most upvoted answer in [Is HttpSession thread safe, are set/get Attribute thread safe operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616601/is-httpsession-thread-safe-are-set-get-attribute-thread-safe-operations)). No spring confusion, but more cumbersome.

Given you use sticky sessions, I recon synchronization on session parameters should be safe even in a clustured environment?

Answer (score 0):

I would favor your second solution, but doing a check before synchronizing (it's expensive) and another check in the synchronized block.

```
public List<Pojo> getPojos() {
     if (!hasTriedToRetrievePojos) {
         synchronized(lock) {
             if (!hasTriedToRetrievePojos) {
                 hasTriedToRetrievePojos = true;
                 service.getPojos();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

The service instance should be singleton as long as it doesn't contain any user/session relevant state at its instance level.

This solution has the advantage that the synchronization is encapsulated in `Model` only and does not rely on the correct configuration of `Service` (as in the first solution - e.g. `@Scope("singleton")` on the service would lead to a different behaviour). Besides that, first solution should work, too. Instead of `@Scope("request")` you could use `@Scope("session")`.

If sticky sessions means a user's session is bound to one appserver instance and each of this user's requests gets directed to this instance, I would say yes, it is safe.

Comment: Double checked locking is broken. Synchronisation is not so expensive in a session-scoped ReST request